# URL amigável não funciona do jeito que eu preciso

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, url-amigável

tenho o seguinte htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^imprensa/?$ imprensa.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^imprensa/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ ler-impresso.php?p=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

o que teria que fazer é que quando acessar `/imprensa` ele teria que carregar o arquivo `imprensa.php` agora se acessar dessa forma `/imprensa/postagem-teste`

ele teria que carregar o arquivo `ler-impresso.php` passando o texto `postagem-teste` na variavel `p`

alguém sabe onde estou errando ?

Comment: Aqui funciona normalmente, poderia explicar qual erro exatamente ocorre?

Comment: quando acesso meusite.com.br/imprensa ele carrega o arquivo imprensa.php mas quando acesso meusite.com.br/imprensa/titulo-da-postagem ele carrega o mesmo arquivo imprensa.php e não o arquivo ler-impresso.php

Comment: Será que não é o cache ou algo assim? No localhost ocorre o mesmo problema? Verifica se fez o upload corretamente.

Comment: Veja se ajuda Search Friendly URLs | Instant .htaccess generator  http://searchfriendlyurls.com/

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste e consegui da seguinte forma:

```
# imprensa
RewriteRule ^(imprensa)$ imprensa.php [NC,L]
# imprensa/teste
RewriteRule ^(imprensa)/(.*?)$ ler-imprensa.php?p=$2 [NC,L]
```

Ou se quiser utilizar com ID na URL:

```
# imprensa/123/teste
RewriteRule ^(imprensa)/([0-9]+)/(.*?)$ ler-imprensa.php?id=$2&p=$3 [NC,L]
```